TV Show about criminals serving in the French Foreign Legion instead of going to jail
Some years ago I saw a (I think it was) British, TV-show which was a little like Bad Lads Army but in the French Foreign Legion.
The show was about some minor criminals - people who got into bar fights, mugged people etc - who were sent to a fort in Algeria to train as French Foreign Legionnaires for some weeks. I think if they didn't quit during the time they were to go free without jail time.
The first night they had to listen to old German songs all night and some of them got really angry because they couldn't sleep.
I remember it to be really cool but I can't seem to find it anywhere.
Does anybody know the name of the show?

So some years ago is the early 2000's? 90's? Also if you could add as much detail as you can that would infinitely help. Stuff like what the cast was like, what storylines/jokes you remember ... etc.

Escape to the Legion with Bear Grylls in 2005? 


Bear filmed a four-part TV show in 2005, called Escape to the Legion,
  which followed Grylls and eleven other “recruits” as they took part in
  a shortened re-creation of the French Foreign Legion’s basic desert
  training in the Sahara. The show was broadcast in the UK on Channel 4,
  and in the USA on the Military Channel. In 2008, it was repeated in
  the UK on the History Channel
For generations, the French Foreign Legion has been romanticized as a
  refuge for men seeking a second chance in life. But what is it really
  like? In Escape to the Legion, adventurer and explorer Bear Grylls
  sets off to find out with 11 other recruits who come from all walks of
  life.
A disorderly band of men arrive at an ex-Legion fort in the Sahara
  Desert to attempt a month’s brutal training that promises to turn them
  in honorary members of the world’s toughest fighting force. Their
  journey will reveal as much about the men themselves as it does about
  the Foreign Legion. Find out where Bear Grylls got his inspiration
  from, hear from the recruits in their own words, and read what a
  psychologist has to say about their teamwork.

